# Netsuite sql case statement where both are true

Tags: sql, netsuite

I am trying to create a formula for the following criteria.

WHEN usernotes.notetitle CONTAINS ‘collection’ AND usernotes.notedate is within the last thirty days

Here is what I have right now. It lets me write a case then set the value.

```
CASE WHEN ({usernotes.notetitle} CONTAINS 'collection') AND (TRUNC({today}-{usernotes.notedate}) BETWEEN 0 AND 30) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

I don’t know if CONTAINS is the right syntax and I’m not sure if I can combine the two formulas or if I did it right.

Comment: what error message are you receiving? Not an expert with netsuite but maybe try using Like %collection% instead of Contains.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are combining your conditions correctly with AND.

To do string comparisons, use `LIKE` and the `%` wildcard:

```
CASE WHEN ({usernotes.notetitle} LIKE '%collection%') AND (TRUNC({today}-{usernotes.notedate}) BETWEEN 0 AND 30) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

If you only need to look for notes that *start with* `collection`, then just remove the first `%`.

See the NetSuite Help article titled *SQL Expressions* for details on all the SQL functions you can use.

See [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions007.htm) on `LIKE` for more details about pattern matching.